# Sharing the new AWS HTTP API between functions in serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm using the serverless framework and I'm trying to test the new HTTP API (instead of the REST API) to improve performance. Currently, I create my REST API separately and then reference that restApiId and the restApiRootResourceId when I declare my functions like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: xka8g7ds
    restApiRootResourceId: 79sdvuejs7
functions:
  myFunction: ${file(./lambdas/myFunction.yml)}
```

This works fine with the REST API, however, I'm not sure how to do this with the new HTTP API. I don't see a way of referencing a 'httpApiId' instead of a 'restApiId' and when creating a HTTP API it doesn't even return a restApiRootResourceId.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it myself. You can do it like this:

```
provider:
  httpApi:
    id: ApiID # ID of externally created HTTP API to attach resources
    timeout: 5
```

I found it in this blog post: https://serverlessguru.com/resources/blog/2020-03-03_Amazon-API-Gateway-HTTP-APIs-with-the-Serverless-Framework-7be95f305318

Comment: I would recommend if you are looking for a configuration, check out the serverless.yml reference page. It has all sorts of good info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/#serverlessyml-reference

Answer (score 0):

You never need to do this with the Serverless Framework. If you just attach an HTTP event to a function it will automatically create the API for you. The same is true of the new HTTP API. If you need to add additional configuration, there are a lot of options built into the Serverless Framework to perform that customisation (https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#api-gateway) but you can also do so using CloudFormation in the `resources` section of the serverless.yml file.

Bundling all required resources (as much as possible) into the same service is generally preferred when developing these services as it makes for a more portable and easily deployable service. Being able to easily deploy a service in any environment has advantages in testing and developer productivity as you can have two or more developers working on the same service but testing off seperate instances, reducing conflict in development.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I am aware that serverless can/will create the API. But we have more than a 100 endpoints and want all those endpoints to use a single API Gateway, also as we use custom domains. This works with the REST API, but I'm not sure how to do this with the HTTP API.